# How do I make this verify if strLetter is not a number?

Tags: vb.net

I've tried putting all of the code into a if-else statement and another do-loop. Either way as soon as i type in the number into the inputBox it ends the program. How do i get it to continue?

```
Private Sub mnuFileNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileNew.Click

    Dim strWord As String
    Dim strLetter As String
    Dim blnValidWord As Boolean
    Dim blnDashReplaeced As Boolean
    Dim blnGameOver As Boolean
    Dim intIncorrect As Integer

    ' Hide the picture boxes
    picBottom.Visible = False
    picPost.Visible = False
    picTop.Visible = False
    picRope.Visible = False
    picHead.Visible = False
    picBody.Visible = False
    picRightArm.Visible = False
    picLeftArm.Visible = False
    picRightLeg.Visible = False
    picLeftLeg.Visible = False

    ' get a 5-letter word from player 1 and convert to uppercase
    strWord = InputBox("Enter a word up to ten letters:", "Hangman Game").ToUpper

    ' determine whether the word contains 5 letters
    blnValidWord = True ' assume the word is valid
    If strWord.Length >= 10 Then
        blnValidWord = False
    Else
        Dim intIndex As Integer
        Do While intIndex >= 10 AndAlso blnValidWord = True
            If strWord.Substring(intIndex, 1) Like "[!A-Z]" Then
                blnValidWord = False
            End If
            intIndex = intIndex + 1
        Loop
    End If

    If blnValidWord = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a word up to ten letters.", "Hangman Game", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Else

        Select Case strWord.Length
            Case 1
                lblWord.Text = "-"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 2
                lblWord.Text = "--"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 3
                lblWord.Text = "---"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 4
                lblWord.Text = "----"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 5
                lblWord.Text = "-----"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 6
                lblWord.Text = "------"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 7
                lblWord.Text = "-------"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 8
                lblWord.Text = "--------"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 9
                lblWord.Text = "---------"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
            Case 10
                lblWord.Text = "----------"
                ' display five dashes in lblWord and clear lblIncorrect
                lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty
        End Select

        ' get a letter from player 2 and convert to uppercase
        strLetter = InputBox("Enter a letter:", "Letter", "", 600, 400).ToUpper
        ' verify that player 2 entered a letter
        ' and that the games is not over
        Do While strLetter <> String.Empty AndAlso blnGameOver = False
            ' Search the word for the letter
            Dim intWordCount As Integer = strWord.Length - 1
            For intIndex As Integer = 0 To intWordCount
                ' if the letter appears in the word, then
                ' replace the dash in lblWord and
                ' indicate that a replacement was made
                If strWord.Substring(intIndex, 1) = strLetter Then

                    lblWord.Text = lblWord.Text.Remove(intIndex, 1)
                    lblWord.Text = lblWord.Text.Insert(intIndex, strLetter)
                    blnDashReplaeced = True

                End If
            Next intIndex

            ' determine whether a dash was replaced
            If blnDashReplaeced = True Then
                ' if the word does not contain any dashes,
                ' the game is over because player 2
                ' guessed the word; otherwise, reset the 
                ' blnDashReplaced variable for the next search
                If lblWord.Text.Contains("-") = False Then
                    blnGameOver = True
                    MessageBox.Show("Great guessing!", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Else
                    blnDashReplaeced = False
                End If
            Else ' processed when no dash was replaced
                ' display the incorrect letter, then update
                ' the intIncorrect variable, then show
                ' the appropriate picture box
                lblIncorrect.Text = lblIncorrect.Text & " " & strLetter
                intIncorrect = intIncorrect + 1
                Select Case intIncorrect
                    Case 1
                        picBottom.Visible = True
                    Case 2
                        picPost.Visible = True
                    Case 3
                        picTop.Visible = True
                    Case 4
                        picRope.Visible = True
                    Case 5
                        picHead.Visible = True
                    Case 6
                        picBody.Visible = True
                    Case 7
                        picRightArm.Visible = True
                    Case 8
                        picLeftArm.Visible = True
                    Case 9
                        picRightLeg.Visible = True
                    Case 10
                        picLeftLeg.Visible = True
                        blnGameOver = True
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the word is " & strWord & ".", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End Select
            End If
            If blnGameOver = False Then

                strLetter = InputBox("Enter a letter", "Letter", "", 600, 400).ToUpper

            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Use [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if the string is an integer.

Comment: It will end the program if strLetter is empty and blnGameOver = false

Comment: Your loop looks alright to me.  I think you have a different problem than what you posted here.

Comment: You'd need more of your code for a decent answer.  From what I can see, I don't see any reason that a number would cause it to exit immediately.

Comment: I just ran it - I don't see the behavior you are describing.  When I run it a number is treated just like any other incorrect guess.

Comment: I wasnt clear... i need it to not accept numbers... My resolution is below.

Comment: You can replace that ugly Select Case with 2 lines of code:  `lblWord.Text = New String("-"c, strWord.Length)  lblIncorrect.Text = String.Empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why it would end immediately, but here's what I'd try assuming that you want only one letter at a time:

```
Dim strLetter As Char
Do Until Char.IsLetter(strLetter) = True
    strLetter = InputBox("Enter a letter:", "Letter", "", 600, 400).ToUpper
Loop
```

That should limit the input to only the first character from the inputbox, and will keep displaying the input box until a letter is selected.

Comment: ok great! that worked. Heres what i did...
            Do
                strLetter = InputBox("Enter a letter:", "Letter", "", 600, 400).ToUpper
            Loop Until Char.IsLetter(CChar(strLetter)) = True

Comment: Good.  If you want to limit the input to one character, I might recommend creating another form that you can pop up with a text field that you can limit to one character.  I think you'll find that it will give you lots of advantages.

Answer (score 0):

In the textbox's KeyPress event, add:

If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handled = True
End If

Comment: It's an inputBox that pops up not a textbox.